# canvas.drawtext() method puts the textview at the beginning (0,0), how do I set actual position of textview?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using ontouchlistener to drag and drop/place the textview on the imageview. The imageview get produced properly upon exporting, but the textview put on it doesn't. 
I hope someone can help me fix this, thank you.

ontouchlistener code:

```
editwalatext.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        xCoOrdinate = v.getX() - event.getRawX();
                        yCoOrdinate = v.getY() - event.getRawY();

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        v.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate).y(event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start();
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
```

code for drawing textview on canvas

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                picture.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                final Bitmap b = picture.getDrawingCache();

                        w = b.getWidth();
                        h = b.getHeight();

                        String iptext = editwalatext.getText().toString();


                mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,w,h,true);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
                canvas.drawText(iptext, textwidght, textheight, textPaint);

                        try {
                            File newfile = savebitmap(mBitmap);
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                        }
            }
        });
```

The textwidght and textheight are equal to variables xCoOrdinate and yCoOrdinate respectively of ontouchlistener method.
I'm new to android programming, sorry if i'd made a silly mistake.

Comment: Setting (x,y) coordinates on a `View` specifies the position of the top-left corner of the `View`. However, the coordinates you pass to `Canvas#drawText()` are for the leftmost baseline point of the text; basically, the bottom left of where most letters sit on a line.

Comment: @MikeM. thank you for explaining, can you please give me idea about how may I achieve the desired thing? example will be much appreciated :)